# simple jquery chat box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How could I create a simple popup chatbox which sticks to the bottom right of the page using jquery? Just like facebook or google. I want the animationto fade in out instead of slide. I just need it to pop up, nothing else.

```
.chat{
width:200px;
height:300px;
background:#000;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
right:0;
}

.close{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 }


 <div class="chat">
 <div class="close">x</div>
 some content
 </div>

 <a href="#" class="trigger">Click here</a>
```

Comment: please, define your problem. we cannot expect what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For `fade in` and `fade out`. Example:

$('#element').fadeIn();

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Same with fadeOut();

About `stick position`:

You can do it with using CSS. Example:

```
#element {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 100; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z69CK/)